# Upgrade Minor Version of Postgres in Debian using apt

Tags: debian, postgresql

I'm trying to move from 9.1.3 to 9.1.4.  I thought all I had to do was "apt-get update" and "apt-get upgrade", but that didn't work.  It did install some updates, but that was only for 9.1.3.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

`apt-get` will upgrade to the packages available in the repository from the source that `apt` is configured to use.

The `postgresql-9.1` package is version 9.1.4 in the `squeeze-backports` repository.

Add the following to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.sources.list`

```
deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main contrib non-free
```

Then run:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install postgresql-9.1
```

If you're Wheezy, 9.1 will already be available. If you're running a release prior to Squeeze then you should first concern yourself with upgrading to Squeeze.

Comment: You will want to pass `-t squeeze-backports` to that install command. Backports priority is set to 100 by default. See http://backports-master.debian.org/Instructions/

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Normally yes, but in this case it's not necessary because squeeze doesn't have a `postgresql-9.1` package. It's only available in backports and it's being requested explicitly so the backport is automatically selected.

Comment: Sure, but the OP probably doesn't realise that this is a special case. In general it is preferable to quote commands in the form in which they will always work.